# Populate a child list when adding data to the parent list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Using SharePoint Designer, and when adding data to list1, I want the data to be in list 2. A look up column is not the option I'm looking for. It needs to be a separate entry.

What is the workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which version of SharePoint Designer you are using, but the command you want to use in SP2013 is **Create list item**. Then you can update any metadata related to the new item from the source list (there will be a pop-up that will allow you to do this).

Answer (score 1):

From SharePoint Designer, connect to your site collection / or site. You will need to create a new workflow.

a Workflow is a process in SharePoint that will take place due to events, such as adding an item or editing an item. You can also trigger it manually, so you have 3 ways to start it (Add item, Edit item, Manually).

After connecting to your site using SharePoint Designer, choose workflows, and create a new list workflow. You should choose your source list, as this is the list that you want to have the workflow running based on.

Just add one step in that workflow, to create a new item in the destination list. So basically you're telling SharePoint, when an item is added to list A, create an item in list B, and the one that listens to this event is list A using the workflow.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

'this list' is not available because it's in the parent site.  This only works when creating a list item at the same level not parent to child.  That is the issue, connecting to the child list from the parent list in the workflow when using 'Create list item'